# How can I rotate all pages with Simple Scan?

Tags: scanner, simplescan

I'm scanning multiple pages using Simple Scan and the "all pages from feeder" option. How do I rotate all pages? It seems like I can only rotate one page at a time, I can't select all the pages and rotate them.

Answer (score 0):

As the first page is scanning, rotate it as desired. All the subsequent pages will keep the same rotation.

There is no way to select multiple pages and rotate them all at once after they have been scanned, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

If the end result is a pdf, you can rotate multiple pages using `pdfshuffler`, which is in the standard repos.